# How to do a hexdump of first track of HDD?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, dd

How would i do a hexdump in Ubuntu for the first track of a HDD?

I am looking for a winhex-esque output if that makes sense. The first track has 63 sectors, each 512 bytes long. I tried

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=1 count=512 | hexdump -C
```

but that only gave me what appears to be the MBR, or first sector of the HDD. I guess i am confused about what bs and count should be. Bs means how many bytes to display and count is how many multiples of bs? Thanks!

Comment: If i try bs-1 count=32256, it appears to truncate the output to only about two pages worth of scrolling within the terminal... i have no idea why.

Answer (score 12):

`bs` is the block size, in bytes, and `count` is the number of those blocks to grab. So the command you actually want to dump the first track is:

```
dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=63 | hexdump -C
```

The dd [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/dd/) might be of help.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why i'm not seeing the full output? I don't even see the 1st block (MBR) when i type the above command. It shows me output only between 000050d0 and 00007e00.

Comment: Would `hexdump -C -n 32256 /dev/sda` not work?

Comment: Yes, you think that you're using an interactive hexediting program, as on Windows.  You're using a non-interactive program that just dumps everything in one long stream of output, only the last N lines of which are left on your terminal at the end.  The next Unix building block for you to learn is the `more` (or `less`) command.  (-:

Comment: When I finish overwriting my USB stick, I can test this, but couldn't you try to dump it into a file to browse through. Wouldn't `dd if=/dev/sda bs=512 count=63 | hexdump -C > firsttrack.txt` output it to a file?